# javascript - shorten an if statement with numeric comparison

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How could I shorten this if statement?

```
if(month == 1 
|| month == 3
|| month == 5
|| month == 7
|| month == 8
|| month == 10
|| month == 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Array like this

```
if ([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12].indexOf(month) + 1)
```

[`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1`, if the element being searched is not found. Since we add `1` to it, if the element is not found, the expression will become `0` and evaluate to be Falsy.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
if ([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12].indexOf(month) !== -1)
    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

`5546&1<<month` as in `if(5546&1<<month) {}` assuming your numbers are one of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] (actually, up to 31)

This one uses bit packing. 5546 is 0b1010110101010 which is a map of your needed months from 12 to 1 and 1 empty bit(for a shorter record). `1<<month` gets one bit and shifts is month bits left, & selects the month we use, and the resulting number is either 0 or positive int depending on what month was selected, resulting in fast and space efficient check.